# How to get started in image processing

Tags: image-processing

I want to start studying image processing and need some tutorials for beginners. I am not bad at Mathematics and good when it comes to programming. I want to use the `CImg` library and write code in `C++`. Could you advice me some good tutorials or books to start with ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "*A Concise Introduction to Image Processing using C++* "(Chapman & Hall/CRC Numerical Analysis and Scientific Computing Series). If you are interested you can go for OpenCV. It has a large number of tutorials available in the internet

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out "Digital Image Processing using MATLAB, Gonzalez, Rafael C"  if you're going to study image processing, MATLAB could be best choice. otherwise you can use "A Concise Introduction to Image Processing using C++".